# Нужно ли ставить запятую после слов "больше всего", "надеюсь" и "однако"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Ставится ли запятая после слов "больше всего" во фразе "Больше всего мне нравятся пионы", после слова "надеюсь" во фразе "Надеюсь, вы мне поможете", а также после слова "однако"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Больше всего, больше других** – наречные сочетания в значении обстоятельства не обособляются. Но: "больше того" может быть вводным словом.

Например: **Больше того**, эти условия он сам создаёт. [Владимир Войнович (1976)].

2) **Надеюсь**, вы мне поможете. Это обособленное вводное предложение.

3) **Слово "однако" может быть:** а) вводным словом (обособляется); союзом (не обособляется); в) междометием (обособляется).

Надо, **однако**, рассказать об этом подробнее.

**Однако** ужин задерживался. Работать с ним трудно, однако интересно.

Триста тысяч, **однако!**

Answer (score 0):

1. Не ставится
2. Ставится – сложное предложение, разделяет две основы.
3. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm,
   §99. Вводные слова и словосочетания,
   пункт 3, 3-й абзац.

Comment: Розенталь (см. ссылку из ответа) считает слово "надеюсь" вводным, и на этом основании его нужно выделять запятыми. В вашем ответе другое объяснение.

Comment: Можно и вводным. Можно и мое объяснение. Или нет?